# Java queue library

Tags: java, queue

I am working on a project where we have multiple sources (> 500) which  send messages to our system (10 messages per second). The way sources send messages can be different between two sources (filesystem, or using a socket, ...).

Messages are simple, they contain an identifier and position of the object, but we can imagine to receive different format of messages. Our buffer need to do 2 different things.

- First is about the display, every 10 seconds or 10000 messages a notification containing the position of the objects need to be sent. If between two publications we receive two positions for a single identifier we keep the last one. After a publication we restart with an empty buffer.
- Second is about saving all the positions received, in this case we need to keep all the positions of an object between two publications. After a publication we restart with an empty buffer.

[image: Buffer]

Even if it seems not too complicated to make it  from scratch, my question is: Is there an existing library I can use to do this and who will do it better than I can do?

Comment: voting to close but still suggesting you take a look at Spring Integration.